# Why global variable in swift file doesn't look like initialized correctly at debugging?

Tags: swift, debugging, global-variables

my code is very simple, in ContentView.swift file:

```
import SwiftUI

struct NavTab {
    let name: String
}

let tab0 = NavTab(name: "tab0")

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .onAppear {
                print("tab0.name is \(tab0.name)")     // Line 1
            }
    }
}
```

Run the code, it will print tab0.name is "tab0", that's right.

But if you add a breakpoint at Line 1, then interrupted at the breakpoint, enter "po tab0.name" in debug console, you will see tab0.name is equal to "":

```
(lldb) po tab0.name
""

(lldb) po tab0
▿ NavTab
  - name : ""
```

Why is that? Am I misunderstanding something? Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that global variables and static properties are computed lazily (see the [Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html) on this):

> Global constants and variables are always computed lazily, in a similar manner to Lazy Stored Properties. Unlike lazy stored properties, global constants and variables don’t need to be marked with the lazy modifier.
>
> Local constants and variables are never computed lazily.

When the breakpoint is hit, "Line 1" is not run yet, so the global constant `tab0` is no yet computed, and so its value is all zeros. When interpreted as a `String`, that represents the empty string.

You can verify this by adding an initialiser that prints something:

```
struct NavTab {
    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        print("init!")
    }
}

@main
struct testApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        print("ContentView!")
        return WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

and see that it is not called until after the `print("tab0.name is \(tab0.name)")` line. Output:

```
ContentView!
init!
tab0.name is tab0
```

But that's only half of the picture. Why doesn't evaluating `tab0.name` in LLDB call the getter of `tab0` and cause it to be initialised?

I didn't find any documentation for this, but I suspect that this is a quirk of LLDB. I *suspect* that when you do `po tab0.name`, LLDB directly accesses the area of memory where `tab0` is stored, rather than call its getter (as an optimisation perhaps?). It knows where `tab0` is because you are currently in the same file as where `tab0` is declared. If `tab0` were declared in another file, then `po tab0.name` would cause `tab0` to be initialised as you would expect:

```
(lldb) po tab0.name
init!
"tab0"
```

which is why I suspect that this is just a quirk of LLDB.